# Read the same file from different folders

Tags: r, loops, file

I have 2 large datasets (df1 and df2) that exhausts R memory if I read and manipulate it all at once. I have therefore split both my datasets into different "groups" and saved them in two separate folders (path1 and path2) with each constituent file in the folder named "group[i].RDS". Important to note that groups correspond across datasets. That is df1$group[i] also exists in df2.

I used this code to save split files into two folders each :

```
#folder 1
split_data_1 <-
split(df1,f = df1$groups ) 

lapply(names(split_data_1), function(x) {
  x1 <- split_data_1 [[x]]
  saveRDS(x1, file=paste0(path1,'/', x, '.RDS'))
})
#folder2
split_data_2 <-
split(df2,f = df2$groups ) 

lapply(names(split_data_2), function(x) {
  x1 <- split_data_2 [[x]]
  saveRDS(x1, file=paste0(path2,'/', x, '.RDS'))
})
```

Now I want to read_rds() the same group [i] from both folders so that files group_i.RDS from both folders are both loaded in my environment so that I can perform a roll join between these files before I save the output to a new folder. Then I repeat/loop this process for every group [i].  My problem is that I do not know how to read the same group [i] from both folders each time.

Please assist in reading the same group[i] file in each iteration of the loop. I can code the roll join function and saving.

Comment: `rds` files cannot be read in partial; in order to filter for just a specific `$group`, you must read in all data before filtering. Other storage methods do offer the ability to read in only as needed, including the `arrow` package (in immutable parquet files, or via `arrow::read_csv_arrow` for example). Other options include SQL database files (e.g., SQLite or DuckDB).

Comment: I do not mean that files need to be read in partial. Each df is split into groups (the same groups for df1 and df2). The split files are named after groups for example group_i.RDS. What i want to do is read the same file from both folders at the same time. The same file refers to reading group_i.RDS from folder 1 at the same time as reading group_i.RDS from folder 2. I do not want to filter alread saved files. I just want to read corresponding files (corresponding in their name)

Comment: if the filenames are the same, iterate your regular processing over the results of `files1 <- list.files(path1, pattern="rds$", full.names=TRUE)`, perhaps `dat1 <- readRDS(files1[1])` and then `dat2 <- readRDS(file.path(path2, basename(files[1])))`. Does that follow what you intend to do?

Comment: Thank you for this insight. I intend to read corresponding files into R environment and then join this files, do calculations, save and repeat for every group(i). It is therefore crucial that I read the same files from both folders - same as in with the same name which is the group(i).

Comment: Yes, and that is what my comment allows. Instead of using my hard-coded `[1]` as above, you would likely iterate such as `for (fn in files1) { dat1 <- readRDS(fn); dat2 <- readRDS(file.path(path1, basename(fn))); out <- do_something(dat1, dat1); saveRDS(out, file.path(newpath, basename(fn))); }`, or something loosely like that.

Comment: thanks @r2evans this is indeed what I aim to do. Thanks for file.path(path1,basename(fn)) insight!